# Android Studio 1.2.2 - Gradle Build Permission Denied

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, permission-denied

I just get "Permission Denied" issue after reinstalling android studio 1.2.2 on my MAC OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

I can build the android code in terminal by adding `sudo` in the beginning of gradle command. e.g. `sudo gradle build` or `sudo ./gradlew build`. However, even though **I have successfully built** the android app using terminal,it does seem annoying to me that I can't use the android studio as the yellow warning pop up to me (see screenshots)

[image: Yellow Warning Pop-up in Android Studio]

I have tried running the android Studio in root mode, but no luck.

```
sudo /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

In addition, I have also tried the solution by providing the executable mode for gradle files. I have added `chmod +x gradlew` in project directory (as you can see in the screenshot) and in studio directory at `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1`

[image: list of files## Heading ##]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the gradle permission denied in Android Studio 1.2.2?

Comment: Do not use `sudo`. At this point, it would be best to delete your installation and download it again. I suggest you use `homebrew` and download `intellij` or `android studio` for management.

Comment: @JaredBurrows thanks for the suggestion. But it is really painful for me to re-download the android studio. Since I lived in bad internet connection..

Comment: Why would you "re-download"? If you already have it downloaded, then go ahead and re-install it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Please correct me if I am wrong. Isn't it because you've deleted and tried to install it using `homebrew` way?

Comment: I did, yes. If you have the "installer", remove your current installation and try again.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, I did try it before (without `homebrew`) - remove the current installation (sent it to trash) and drag-drop the installer to application folder. But it didn't work - still the same error. I had to remove `.gradle` folder as answered in my own question.

Comment: @JaredBurrows it needs at least 2 days to mark it as correct ~.~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81495/discussion-between-exodream-and-jared-burrows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to solve it.

Just remove the `.gradle` directory `rm -fr .gradle` in `/Users/YOUR_NAME/.gradle`. Then, execute the android studio in root mode.

Answer (score 11):

Just add x permission to gradlew file in your project folder.
Like this:

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

Comment: Thanks Man , it worked . Now I am able to run ./gradlew signingReport

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to your project folder and right click. Then go to 'Get Info' a pop up appears. Then go down to a small lock on your right and click it. If asked for a password enter it and give permission. Then go back to the pop up and look for your name, click your name and and then look for a small * and next to it you will find a dropdown. Click it and it will open 'Apply to enclosed items'. Click it to give access and permission to your project. After that go to Android Studio and close your project and then restart Android Studio and run your project. The error should be gone, that is how I solved my problem too.